# Implicit conversion to make generic type available

Tags: scala

I am using a library which has a class that has a generic type that can be quite complicated.  I need to write a method that takes a parameter with the generic type that a val of the library class has, and I would like to avoid having to write out the type in the method signature.  I thought I might be able to create an implicit class which adds a type to the val that I could use in the method signature, kind of like:

```
// This comes from a library and can't be changed
case class LibraryClass[A](a: A)

//----------------------------------

object MyCode {
  val thing = LibraryClass(3)

  implicit class LibraryClassWithType[A](lc: LibraryClass[A]) {
    type TheType = A
  }

  def doStuff(something: thing.TheType): Unit = {
    println(something)
  }
}
```

This does not compile (TheType is not a member of LibraryClass).  But if I wrap it in the class myself, it works

```
  val thingWithType = LibraryClassWithType(thing)
  def doStuff(something: thingWithType.TheType): Unit = {
    println(something)
  }
```

Is there something I am missing that will make this work, or is this kind of implicit conversion not valid Scala?

Comment: Interesting question! But why you can't just write `doStuff(something: Int): Unit` as you defaulted to `Int` in your example?

Comment: I could, but the problem is this is related to Play Anorm DB stuff, so the type is more like ~[~[~[~[Int, Boolean], String], String], Int]] (And that's for a somewhat simple table) and I was trying to think of a way to not have to write that out for every table in our DB.  I just felt like the compiler should know the type, so why have to write it out myself?

Comment: Could you still add an real example to your question, and what you'd like to simplify. is `LibraryClassWithType` the `~[~[~[~[Int, Boolean], String], String], Int]]` beast? Also this might be *anorm* related question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to do this sort of thing with implicits, but I have had to do something similar where I just instantiated these sorts of type holders:

```
case class LibraryClass[A](a: A)

object MyCode {
  val thing = LibraryClass(3)

  class HigherTypeHolder[A,F[A]](a: F[A]) {
    type AT = A
  }
  val th = new HigherTypeHolder(thing)

  def doStuff(something: th.AT): Unit = {
    println(something)
  }
}
```

Comment: I like how you have a more generic class to add the type, that is cool.  If only it could be converted implicitly...

Comment: Yeah me too, it's one of those funny situations where you really feel like this workaround shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what (I think)  you want like this:

```
implicit val thing = LibraryClass(3)
def doStuff[A](something: A)(implicit lc: LibraryClass[A])
```

What I don't understand is why this needs to be so complicated. Why not for example stick with your second approach, without implicits, that works, or why not just do 
`def doStuff[A](something: A)` to begin with?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think an implicit parameter will help because this code will be called from elsewhere in the code and there may be more than one of LibrayClass with the same type imported in scope.  I could do it without the implicits, because yes it does work.  I guess I am maybe more just curious why the implicit conversion doesn't work, it seems like it should work to me.

Comment: I see ... How about `def doStuff[A](something: A)(lc: LibraryClass[A] = thing)` ?